# The system reports 200Gb is used while there is only 40Gb

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

The `df` returns 216G out of 512 is used:

```
 df -t ext4 -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       468G  216G  229G  49% /
```

The same data returns Discs app:

[image]

I have checked the files in many way and I can't find where those 216G are coming from. Example:

[image]

### Question

How to diagnose what takes up the space?

Comment: Check the entire "/". Your /home uses 39 GB, so all the rest must be elsewhere in the file system. It would not be normal for the system itself to use the missing 177 GB. System files rarely need more than 20 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed @vanadium advice and ran `ncdu -x /`

It turned out the Docker Overlay files took about 170 gigs. The problem is decribed here: https://forums.docker.com/t/some-way-to-clean-up-identify-contents-of-var-lib-docker-overlay/30604/14.

Now working up on cleaning up the Docker overlay files.

[image]

Just to be crystal clear:

1. Ran `docker system prune -a`
2. After that:

```
df -h -t ext4
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       468G   35G  411G   8% /
```

Answer (score 1):

I would `cd /`, `sudo du -sh * |sort -nr` should give you the director that is taking up the space. and you can go from there.